# textarea fields parsing technique

Tags: java, xml, parsing

I have a jsp page of elements mapped with XML mapping. One of the textarea field is parsing the elements if you enter `> or <` special characters to `&gt;` and `&lt;` and `&amp;`. This is giving problem while parsing XML elements.

suppose IF i have an textarea field name like `<Explain>` . Then i have entered the value as **<** as given here: `<Explain> < </Explain>`. Here the field is converting to `&amp;/Explain>` How can i avoid this problem.

I have a code in my java file like this.

```
if(elementStr.indexOf("&") != -1)
    elementStr = elementStr.replaceAll("&[^a][^m][^p][^;]", "&amp;");
```

How can i avoid parsing the special characters to symbols.

Answer (score 0):

You can simple use this:

```
      ${fn:escapeXml(elementStr)};
```

where is your String

Comment: can i enter this in a java file?

Comment: This is for jsp. For java we have different thing StringEscapeUtils.escapeXML("My s<String>ahsdaf"). Accept the answer if you feel it is appropriate thanks

Comment: Sure. But Still i am facing the issue. `&amp;/Explain>`I have given as `if(elementStr.indexOf("&") != -1) StringEscapeUtils.escapeXml(elementStr);`.

Comment: what u r doing here is you are replacing your all > < characters by &amp; why you need that to do

Comment: When ever i submit my form with `>` or `<` values those are converting as `&gt;` and `&lt;`. The XML is reading as `&lt;/Explain>`. I don't understand why this is happening. this is happening in debugging. Once it is released it is converting to `&amp;/Explain>` with the above logic.